# Android SQLite insert method small clarification

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

i am learning some sqlite tutorial for android development and i try to understand this line of code:

```
1  ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
2        values.put(AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_NAME, "Toto");
3        values.put(AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_BREED, "Terrier");
4        values.put(AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT, 7);
5
6
7
8        long newRowId = db.insert(AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
```

Is this line of code (on line 8) inserting my values into the table ? or i am just storing the row id into the long type variable called "newRowId" ?
I ask because the data is inserted but i don't understand why ... because i thought that i am just storing the row id on that line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Is this line of code (on line 8) inserting my values into the table ?

-> Yeah line 8 will insert your value into the table if `db` is initialized with   [SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper#getWritableDatabase()) method.

#### or i am just storing the row id into the long type variable called "newRowId"?

-> When you insert with [SQLiteDatabase.insert()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) it returns the row ID of the newly inserted row, or -1 if an error occurred.

Answer (score 1):

The [SQLiteDatabase `insert`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#insert(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues)) method inserts a row and returns the rowid of the inserted row as a long or in the case of a conflict -1 to indicate that the row was not inserted. So the value of newRowId will either be a positive value greater than 0 if the row was inserted or -1 if not inserted and there was no other conflict (e.g. a Foreign Key constraint conflict will result in an exception being thrown).

- [conflicts](https://sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html) could be a PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, CHECK or NULL constraint violation.

The **`insert`** method is a convenience method that generates the underlying SQL binding any parameters and executes that. The SQL generated will be something like:-

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO the_table_name (the_name_column, the_breed_column, the_weight_column) VALUES(?,?,?);
```

Where:-

- **`the_table_name`** will be the value as per the first parameter i.e. whatever `AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.TABLE_NAME` resolves to.
- **`the_name_column`** will be the value as per the first value of the first in ContentValues (i.e. the value that `AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_NAME` resolves to)
- **`the_breed_column`** will be value as per the first value of the second `ContentValues` (i.e. the value that `AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_BREED` resolves to)
- **`the_weight_column`** being the first value as per the third `ContentValues` (i.e. the value that `AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT` resolves to)

The **`?`**'s are replaced by the 2nd values of the respective `ContentValues` (first from the first i.e. ***'Toto'***, second from the second i.e. ***'Terrier'*** ....) when the SQL statement is bound. Binding statements correctly encloses the actual values in single quotes and thus protects against SQL Injection.

After executing the  `sqlite3_last_insert_rowid()` interface is invoked the result returned with 0 being converted to -1.

If you weren't to use the convenience method, then to replicate all that it does you would have to code something like :-

```
    db.execSQL("INSERT OR IGNORE INTO " + AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.TABLE_NAME +
            "(" +
            AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_NAME +
            "," + AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_BREED +
            "," + AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.COLUMN_WEIGHT +
            ") " +
            "VALUES(?,?,?)", 
            new String[]
                    {
                            "Toto", 
                            "Terrier", 
                            "7"
                    }
    );
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT last_insert_rowid()",null);
    newRowID = -1;
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        newRowID = csr.getLong(0);
        if (newRowID <= 0) {
            newRowID = -1;
        }
    }
    csr.close();
```

where **`db`** is an instantiated SQLiteDatabase object.

**If your goal is to try to predict the next rowid to be used**, then you could use :-

```
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT max(rowid)+1 FROM " + AppContract.HeadphoneEntry.TABLE_NAME + ";",null);
    long newRowID = 1; // 
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        newRowID = csr.getLong(0);
    }
```

**BUT BEWARE** SQLite does not guarantee that the next inserted row will be 1 greater than the highest existing rowid. If you use AUTO INCREMENT then the sqlite_sequence table stores the highest used rowid for the table and the higher of that and the max(rowid) value will be used. **Even then their is still no guarantee that the predicted value will be the value used**. It is far better to not try to predict the value of the rowid but to retrieve it and thus for Android Java to use the convenience method.

- An exception is if you delve into utilising negative rowid values when -1 may then not indicate no insertion.